# using combinatorics to find probability of doublets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$A$ = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

if i make subsets from $A$ such that subsets will only have 2 elements, then i want to find the probability of of doublets appearing. By doublets i mean something like {1,1} , {2,2} and so on.

using simple counting i know the probability should be  $\frac{6}{36}$ as there only 6 doublets and 36 possible subsets with 2 elements.

But if i try this method:
$\frac{^{6}C_{1}}{^{6}C_{1}*^{6}C_{1}}$  by reasoning that the numerator was counted in that manner as i choose one element from for the subset from $A$ then the other element is fixed, i.e the second element is the first element i chose. And the denominator  comes from choosing two element from $A$ with replacement.

Is this logic correct?

Comment: yes that makes sense

Comment: yes, but why not simply $1\cdot\frac16$ ?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja ok, thanks

Comment: @trueblueanil i didn't understand

Comment: The first can be *any* and the next has to be the *same*

Comment: i see, yes i could have written that as $^{6}C_{1}*^{6}C_{0}$ ,  i forgot i could imply that mathematically haha. Now i feel much more confident, thanks

Comment: Actually, my formula deals directly with probabilities, and uses the multiplication law. P(*some* element is drawn)*P(*same* element is drawn) $= 1\cdot\frac16$ A useful variant to keep in mind.

Comment: ohh, i see. Thanks i will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you find the sample space first.
Draw a 2x2 grid to illustrate the reflexive relation aRa for (a,a) E AxA if needed or simple use product rule |a|x|a| = n^r (6x6).
How many reflexive pairs have you got in R? R={(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6)} = 6

Hence P(AxA) = 6/36